# Why does my fire + smoke simulation look chunky?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

I am following this particle explosion tutorial https://youtu.be/29yfS-icS3M and for some reason instead of looking nice and billowy and realistic, it looks like a bunch of floating chunks. My theory is that the smoke is not rendering but I may be wrong. also, I would like to go about this the way the maker of the tutorial does, because I like the idea of having a lot of control over my explosion's material.
My simulation:
[image: My simulation]

The tutorial:
[image: tutorial simulation]

Comment: Is denoising turned on in your viewport?

Comment: no denoising in the viewport but I use nlm for rendering

Comment: I would say it was because your domain resolution was too low.

Comment: my resolution is at 128, same as tutorial. my domain is not unnecessarily large either. basically for each particle there is an orange blob, with no smoke or fire really being emitted.

Answer (score 3):

Ok apparently I hadn't given my simulation long enough to develop; I only baked like 5 frames because the computer i had access to at the time was quite slow. It looks nice after like ten. so if anyone finds that their particle explosion looks like a bean explosion just give it time to bake and it will look great.